# XML and "flags"

Tags: xml, flags

What's the "proper" way to encode a numeric flags variable in XML?

I'm converting a program that dumps data between a couple of systems.
Currently the dump is a tab-separated-values file (tabs shown as ⟿ here):

```
blah de blah ⟿ blargh ⟿ 176 ⟿ ...
```

One of the fields is a number representing a "flags" word in the source DB:

```
#define COURTEOUS     1             /* names changed to protect something */
#define KIND          2
#define FORGIVING     4
#define WITTY         8
#define OBSEQUIOUS   16
#define PURPLE       32
#define HAPPY        64
#define CLAIRVOYANT 128
#define WISE        256
      ...
```

It has been expressed that a number may not be the handiest way to transmit this information.  My current thinking is running along these lines:

```
<things>
    <thing>
        <name>blah de blah</name>
        <owner>blargh</owner>
        <flags value='176'>
            <flag>OBSEQUIOUS</flag>
            <flag>PURPLE</flag>
            <flag>CLAIRVOYANT</flag>
        </flags>
            ...
    </thing>
        ...
</things>
```

Is this a sensible approach?  Is there some sort of standard approach to this?
Would this:

```
        <flags value='176'>
            <OBSEQUIOUS/>
            <PURPLE/>
            <CLAIRVOYANT/>
        </flags>
```

be an improvement?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not really sensible since you present the information twice, in two forms, and future changes can make this inconsistent.  It makes more sense to transmit the text strings and ignore the numeric value. That way you're encoding the semantics only, not an implementation detail of a bitmask.

Comment: My thinking on including the numerical value was for backwards compatibility with things that were happy with the old format and didn't want to go to the trouble of encoding the various flags back into a numeric value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer the to use tags to represent structure rather than content, so my preference would be to use your first option

```
<flag>OBSEQUIOUS</flag>
<flag>PURPLE</flag>
<flag>CLAIRVOYANT</flag>
```

If you are using an XML schema, you can use an enumeration to validate that the values of your flag fields are within a predefined set. The schema then acts as documentation to the user of your XML format making the valid values explicit (if you do indeed know all the possible values at the time you are designing the schema.).

```
<xs:simpleType name='Beatle' >
  <xs:restriction base='xs:string' >
    <xs:enumeration value='OBSEQUIOUS' />
    <xs:enumeration value='PURPLE' />
    <xs:enumeration value='CLAIRVOYANT' />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

As others have commented, there is no good reason to store both the bitarray value and the flags themselves. In some circumstances you could store the bitarray value *only*, for example if the size of the XML file must be kept as small as possible, or for performance reasons. This would sacrifice readability and portability so should only be done if the trade off for performance is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

The semantic meaning of the flags is properly encoded in the names for each flag.  The numeric value is merely an implementation detail.  You should encode in XML ONLY the flag names and not the numeric value. This preserves the semantics without tying you to a specific implementation.

```
 <flags>
        <OBSEQUIOUS/>
        <PURPLE/>
        <CLAIRVOYANT/>
 </flags>
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on your design objectives, but it we assume that you're after clarity, ease of change, readability etc rather than compactness, then my choice would probably be a space-separated list, like

```
<flags value="OBSEQUIOUS PURPLE CLAIRVOYANT"/>
```

described in the schema as

```
<xs:simpleType name='Beatle' >
  <xs:list>
    <xs:restriction base='xs:string' >
      <xs:enumeration value='OBSEQUIOUS' />
      <xs:enumeration value='PURPLE' />
      <xs:enumeration value='CLAIRVOYANT' />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:list>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I feel uneasy about @JimGarrison's design, but I'm not sure why. I think it's probably to do with how you would write template rules to process it in XSLT. If you go down the schema-aware route, then you can declare each of the elements to be a member of a substitution group FLAG, and you can write:

```
<xsl:template match="schema-element(FLAG)">...
```

but you don't always want your processing to be schema-aware. You've still got the option of

```
<xsl:template match="flags/*">...
```

but I think most people feel more comfortable having an element name that they can use directly as a handle in processing applications.